# Speeding up queries in pg_search that use associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, full-text-search, pg-search

I have a Rails app that uses the [pg_search](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search) gem to leverage the Full Text Search capabilities of PostgreSQL.

The manual says about searching a model that has (for instance) a has_many relation:

> ### Searching through associations
>
> It is possible to search columns on associated models. Note that if you do this, it will be impossible to speed up searches with database indexes. However, it is supported as a quick way to try out cross-model searching.

The last lines seems to suggest that this is a good way to prototype searching through associations. And yes, it works indeed. But I typically have a 10 second latency for returning results. Is there a way to to have cross-model searching that is also fast?

Is it: search both models separately, then merge the results?

Comment: Did you ensure that you have a index on the table that is used by the model that has the belongs_to association?  If not or you don't know, post the schema and we can write it for you

Comment: Hey. Do you mean my schema.rb? I think in the migration I execute some PostgreSQL command that Rails doesn't recognize, should I add them with `add_index` as well? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did as a workaround, added a str_* column to my main table, and update this column when an element is saved:

```
  before_validation(on: :save) do
    self.str_abbreviations = join_abbreviations()
    # ... etc, append all columns I'd like to search through ...
    true
  end
```

Comment: I am sorry, could you please explain what exactly this column stores?

Comment: It stores the appended string of the all columns I'd like to search through. I should've made that more clear.

Comment: I see, thank you for explaining. I was trying to make it all work with pg_search myself and spent a day on it, trying to put all the triggers to change tsv columns, add indexes, make it work though associations and etc and I did, but it worked very slow anyway, maybe I did something wrong, I dont know... But then I simply changed to Sphinx and made it work pretty fast and easily. Maybe you should check it out yourself :)

Comment: by the way, when I was working with pg_search and tried to search like 10 keywords, it could take seconds, if not tens of seconds, which is a bad thing if you use unicorn as a web server, it simply ties its instance. but again, maybe I simply did something wrong